# I'm using ajax call in ASP.NET application and I'm getting entire HTML page as response from jquery Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm developing an ASP.NET web application. Where in login screen I used jQuery Ajax call to connect server side code. In the response from the ajax call Im getting entire HTML page instead of true or false ( the actual result I want from the response).

Below is my server code.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string LoginValidation(string userName, string passWord)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from LoginUser where username = '"
            + userName + "' and password = '" + passWord + "'");
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            return "succes";
        }
        return "failure";
    }
```

Below is my Jquery Ajax call.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtLogin').focus();
});

$('#btnLogin').click(function () {
    var username = $('#txtLogin').val();
    var password = $('#txtPassword').val();

    if (username === "" || password === "") {
        alert('Both the fields are mandatory. Kindly try again');
        $('#txtLogin').focus();
        return;
    }
    else {
        //ajax call to validate the login
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'userName': username, 'passWord': password },
            url: 'Default.aspx/LoginValidation',
            async: true,
            datatype: 'text',
            success: function (data) {
            alert('test sadfadfa '+data+' '+data.responseText);
                if (data == "failure") {
                    //redirecting to master page once after the successfull login
                    window.location.href = "/masterscreen.aspx";
                }
                else {
                    alert('false');
                }
                return;
            },
            error: function (data) {

            }
        });
        //ajax call end
    }
});
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Updated kindly do help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: and your response text ?

Comment: Are you sure that the server side code gets executed? Did you debug? The web method is not configured for post call in your code. What html you are receiving in Ajax response?

Comment: What kind of string that `data` variable holds when AJAX call succeeded? Show the HTML page markup gathered from browser JS console with `success: function(data) { console.log(data); ... }`.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I was previously tested like sending back a string and showed it in a alert box. it works fine and thn only I moved to write code. If you find any mistake kindly let me know. I ll correct it

Comment: What I get as response in ajax call is, entire HTML source code. the response is as similar as page source view in browser.

Comment: Can't say what problem with your code just by looking at it. It looks ok to me. That's why I asked you to debug and figure out what error or exception is occurring. If you know the error it can be fixed

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  I'm getting this error in console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya my breakpoint in the class file is not getting hit.

Answer (score 0):

i've included the contentType in my Ajax call. It resolved my problem. Now, I'm getting JSON response as expected. Hope this helps some one.Thanks for those who helped me out.